# Android oauth2 authorization

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, google-http-client

I have my own oauth2 provider. I have set the grant type as authorization code.
I am able to successfully test this via curl

I would like to implement `oauth` on an android app I am working on. I want to understand the flow.

I have read several documents regarding this topic but I just don't seem to get it.
I want to be able to pass user name and password and follow oauth2 flow.
Really appreciate if someone can paint the picture?

Comment: You can test this [library](https://github.com/AliAbozaid/OAuth2Library)